# What's the song when Bishamon fights in episodes 11 & 12 of Aragoto?

Tags: music, noragami

What is the name of the song in *Noragami Aragoto* episodes 11 and 12 when Bishamon fights? First, against Izanami in the underworld, and then against Kiun, the Thunder Dragon, immediately after rescuing Ebisu from a direct strike.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the music that starts at about 18:18 in episode 11 and 16:25 in episode 12, that is "Distortion" from the [*Noragami Aragoto* OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/56225) (disc 1, track 4). [Here](https://clyp.it/zzzwah0a?token=c8d4232e1743b82f9e2cf6e1160364b0) is a 20-second extract from the beginning of the track.